# Cordova / Ionic build android Gradle error: Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.13

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle, ionic-framework

This is a solution to the above error that I want to document.  I found other similar posts, but none described how this error can be associated with Cordova or Ionic.

If you are not careful, there can be a mismatch between the version of Gradle that Android Studio uses and the version of Gradle that Cordova / cordova-android specifies in its auto-generated application code.  As you know, running

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

(or `$ ionic platform add android`, if you are building an Ionic app) creates  the native application code at the-project/platforms/android.

Inside that folder, the file: /the-project/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js exports a variable as shown below:

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.y-all.zip';
```

Where x and y depened on which version of Cordova / cordova-android are being used to build the native application code.

When you run

```
$ cordova build android
```

The version of Gradle specified in the `distributionUrl` var is the version used for the build.

Now here comes the tricky part.  When you import the project into Android Studio, you will most likely get a message strongly recommending that you upgrade Gradle to a newer version, as shown below:

[image]
If you do this, Android Studio will download a new version of Gradle and store it locally and configure the project to use the newly download local Gradle distribution, which is the radio option below the selected “Use default grade wrapper”, which I ended up deselecting because this will cause errors.

[image]

This will cause problems because Android Studio and Cordova will now be attempting to build the application with different versions of Gradle and you will get build errors within Android Studio and also with

```
$ cordova build android
```

in the command line.  The solution with Cordova apps is to always keep the Android Studio project set to "Use default gradle wrapper" and ignore the tempting messages to upgrade.  If you do want to use a newer version of Gradle, you can always change the distributionUrl var in the file mentioned above (however Cordova strongly discourages modifying code within the platforms folder since it is easily overwritten).  At the time of writing this, I cannot tell is there is a way to set the Gradle version at the

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

step, which is when you would want to do it so you are never directly modifiying code inside of the-project/platforms

Answer (score 27):

For me, the following commands solved the problem:

```
cordova platform remove android

cordova platform add android

ionic build android
```

Comment: I'd add to this "do not open the project in Android Studio again" if that's an option. :)

Comment: As of March 2020, this still fixes the problem.

Answer (score 20):

I'd love to just leave this as a comment, but I'm apparently not reputable enough...

After reading your documentation, I wasn't able to resolve my issue with your suggestion of keeping the Android Studio to "Use default gradle wrapper". What I did find is that setting the session variable CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL before building got me a bit further:

```
root@dev:$ export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip"
root@dev:$ cordova build android
```

The next thing I had to do was edit `<project>/platforms/android/build.gradle` and `<project>/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle` and make sure they both pointed to a valid gradle plugin version.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

...and in `<project>/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle` I added jcenter in the repositories (because maven.org did not seem to have 2.2.0)

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral();
    jcenter()
}
```

I was able to build then.

Comment: You are my hero, pointing CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL and pointing to 2.2.0 was the key!

Comment: Remove double quotes from CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip" because its adding double quotes in gradle-wrapper.properties file in distributionUrl value and generates error in build (java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip""")

Comment: and yes do not forget to use "set" instead of "export". i.e. set CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Comment: Any updates to the files within the platforms folder should not be suggested. Making updates to these files will be overridden if you ever need to update or remove and add the android or iOS Platforms. Which means you cannot ever update Cordova solutions without losing these updates.

Answer (score 9):

Switching back to "Use default gradle wrapper" didn't work for me on my ionic 1 project, but running

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
```

Worked for me

Comment: Still works for Ionic 3/4: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in E:\ionic\MyIonicProject\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.4-all.zip for gradle 4.4

Answer (score 7):

Another way to fix issue, that also works on Windows:

```
cordova build android --release --CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 7):

you can change the value in platform/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js

the value you changed, it will be replaced by the lastest gradle zip when you reinstall android platform, so you don't need to worry about change it

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip';
```

or like the others ans

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip"
```

Comment: Sir means..after change version and remove the platform then add platform again right ?

Answer (score 4):

I want to extend @bungler answer.

I got confused with version of gradle & compatible version of android plugin for gradle. Following link has the list of compatibale versions mapping:

[Gradle vs Android plugin for gradle - Compatible version list](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

For current version of gradle **3.3+**, compatible version of android plugin is **2.3.3**

So final settings will look like following:

> For Mac

STEP 1:  Add following in env variables:

option a) update env variable:

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip"
```

or

option b ) you can download the gradle [file](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip) and place it in `<project>/platforms/android/gradle/` and update env variable:

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="../gradle-3.3-all.zip"
```

STEP 2: Update following in  `<project>/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
  }
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Works for Mac and Linux

Answer (score 2):

For follow error:

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.3. If
>   using t he gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
>   E:\ionic\MyIonicProject\gr adle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to
>   gradle-4.1-all.zip for gradle 4.1

This command worked for me:

```
ionic cordova platform update android
```

Comment: That command did it for me ! thanks EmRa228. Much easier that the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In follow up to Chuck Holbrooks answer, with following solution I get an error when trying to add android platform again saying it is already added.

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

My working Solution:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform check android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run the following it will fix the problem building APKs from the command line

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

however, after you run/build it in android studio the version mismatch error returns...

instead to fix this, in android studio you should NOT update the project gradle versioning but instead go to
file > project structure > SDK location > Gradle settings...
and then tell it to use Gradle from a specified location which should be
C:/Gradle/gradle-7.4.2 or whatever version you have.

By doing this you will be able to build APKs from the command line using ionic as well as from within android studio.