# Ionic App - build fails with "Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4"

Tags: ionic-framework, gradle

This is an Ionic Cordova project. I haven't touched in in a while but I came back to it now and when I run

```
ionic cordova build android
```

I get the following error:

```
 Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1. If using 
the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in 
C:\projects\ghost\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.4- 
all.zip
```

So I did that and had my gradle.properties file looking like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4- 
all.zip
```

But the build still fails and the properties file reverts to have 4.1 listed in it.
I have Gradle 4.9 installed and added to the path but that didn't work either.
Windows 10 Machine.

UPDATE: 
I tried changing the cordova build script in GradleBuilder.js where it referenced gradle 4.1 to have gradle-4.4-all instead but the result was the same.

Thanks for any input.

Steve

Comment: please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354212/cordova-ionic-build-android-gradle-error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrade all your Sdk and do:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.1 or latest
```

this will allow u to correct the gradle problem since it will update the gradle automatic

Comment: Thanks Hitmacreed, I actually got to that point myself last night but this is still the correct answer.